# why CreateDIBSection() fails with certian BITMAPINFO?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, bitmap, createdibsection

I am trying to use `CreateDIBSection`.

Problem:

In Windows XP, I tried to call `CreateDIBSection`, it returns `NULL` and `GetLastError` = 0

When I try to change the screen resolution, for example to 2048 x 1536, it returns correct value.

I have tested this function has some relationship with `nMemSize` (not necessarily small number).

Question:

Is there any guarantee way to ensure `CreateDIBSection` returns correct value?

```
nScreenWidth = 1024;
nScreenHeight= 768;
 = nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight*3*7
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(hWnd);
m_hBmpMapFile = ::CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, nMemSize, NULL);

BITMAPINFO bmpInfo = {0};
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = nScreenWidth;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = nScreenHeight;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = nMemSize;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
bmpInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue = 204;
bmpInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen = 204;
bmpInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbRed = 204;
bmpInfo.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved = 0;
PVOID pvBits;

m_hBmpAllWstDskWallpaper = ::CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, m_hBmpMapFile, 0);
```

Comment: Well, it's not clear why it's failing. I think your question should really be, "why is CreateDIBSection failing?". If you can get an answer to that then you should be able to solve your real problem.

Comment: ok, I have changed it. I think the reail problem is really CreateDIBSection fails when nMemSize change to certian number. sometimes it fails with say 10000, but when u change nMemsize to a larger 20000 it succesed.

Comment: @yyy: Post all fields of `bmpinfo.bmiHeader`. What values you assign to them?

Comment: Please provide the complete code.  It would be much easier for us to tell (or guess) where the problem might be.  And why is it `* 7` in the `nMemSize` equation?

Comment: sorry i just edited. `*3` for RGB bytes, `*7` is for 7 times the screen size. i am making a large horizontal panorama screen.

Comment: Works fine with my windows 7 machine.  Could it actually be another API function failing?  Have you tried calling GetLastError after other API calls?

Comment: Is `nScreenWidth` always evenly divisible by 4?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be contained in the section of code that you did not include (in the elipses ...).  So I recommend:

- Check your Device Context is valid
- ZeroMemory
- Add the structure size
- And bitmap dimensions
- Move the GetLastError calls to ensure that the Device Context is valid (perhaps an earlier API call fails)

The code below seems to work after I added the recommendations above, I hope it helps:

```
        HDC hdc = ::GetDC(hWnd); 
        int nScreenWidth = 1024; 
        int nScreenHeight= 768; 
        int nMemSize = nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight*3*7;
        HANDLE m_hBmpMapFile = ::CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, nMemSize, NULL); 
        BITMAPINFO bmpInfo; 
        //clear the memory
        ZeroMemory(&bmpInfo.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
        //struct size
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof (BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        //dimensions
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = nScreenWidth;
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = nScreenHeight;
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1; 
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; 
        bmpInfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage=nMemSize; 
        void *pvBits = NULL;
        HANDLE m_hBmpAllWstDskWallpaper = ::CreateDIBSection(hdc, &bmpInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &pvBits, m_hBmpMapFile, 0);
        int nError = ::GetLastError();
```